# SpringMVC can't request html

Tags: spring-mvc

SpringMVC can't request html

I define a

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/","/index"}).
```

I can't request index.html:

[image: screenshot of code]

Comment: I have reformatted your question a little, putting the image inline most notably. Stack Overflow welcomes users to edit and re-edit their questions, to improve them as much as possible. In your case, it would be better if you could explain a little more what you are trying to do, how you're trying to do it, and what is going wrong.

Comment: @javajoker Also post your XML config or Java config to check that it's finding the files correctly.  Note that if you don't specify a something like `method = RequestMethod.GET` in your `@RequestMapping` annotation, then it will match to any type of HTTP request.  Also strange is autowiring a User.  You usually retrieve one from a repository and autowire either a repository or a service that calls a repository.

Comment: Thanks,everyone.My english is not good.I can't express my idea.My problme is that @RequestMapping  intercept request "/index.html".  I can't get index.html  in browser.

Comment: Please post your view resolver configuration java/xml

Answer (score 0):

try adding `"/index.html"` to the @RequestMapping.

If you are trying to display the 001.html by going to /index, then make sure your 001.html is in the folder your view resolver is looking at

Answer (score 0):

The value of `@RequestMapping` is not your view name, it's url path.

View name is defined in `return`.Try return `index.html`.

If you defined this in spring-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</bean>
```

You need return `index`.